# Increase number of rsh connections

Tags: rhel7, connections, rsh

We are using a Server with OS **RHEL 7.2** server version. Number of **rsh** connections to the system is limited to a number around 70. We are getting a message **Connection reset by peer** from server as that number gets exhausted.

I want to increase number of **rsh** connections to my system.

**NOTE:** I understand the fact that it is not advised to use rsh and it is better to switch to ssh for operations. But such change is beyond my control. So any help regarding **RSH** connections will be very helpful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration parameter `instances` of `defaults { }` in `/etc/xinetd.conf` sets this globally (*extended Internet daemon* wide). There's no such setting for the individual service configured in `/etc/xinetd.d/rsh`.

Still, it's not secure to use `rsh`, and the best recommendation is to disable it with `disable = yes` and use SSH instead. We are not in the early 90s anymore.

Comment: **/etc/xinetd.conf** file is not available.

Comment: What you mean by that?

Comment: There is no such file available as **xinted.conf** in /etc/ directory.